# Ordenar uma dataframe pelo mes

Tags: python-3.x, data

```
import pandas as pd
```

Suponha o seguinte dataset:

```
data = {
    'ano': [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]*5,
    'mes': ['janeiro']*9 + ['fevereiro']*9 + ['março']*9 + ['abril']*9 + ['maio']*9,
    'valor': [112, 127, 121, 131, 150, 158, 137, 165, 164,
              101, 101, 94, 114, 126, 119, 122, 138, 144,
              97, 101, 101, 123, 126, 138, 137,154 ,114,
              97 ,94 ,97 ,122 ,125 ,141 ,129 ,142 ,6,
              96 ,98 ,98 ,136 ,126 ,135 ,136 ,144 ,4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)


     ano        mes  valor
0   2012    janeiro    112
1   2013    janeiro    127
2   2014    janeiro    121
3   2015    janeiro    131
4   2016    janeiro    150
5   2017    janeiro    158
6   2018    janeiro    137
7   2019    janeiro    165
8   2020    janeiro    164
9   2012  fevereiro    101
10  2013  fevereiro    101
11  2014  fevereiro     94
12  2015  fevereiro    114
13  2016  fevereiro    126
14  2017  fevereiro    119
15  2018  fevereiro    122
16  2019  fevereiro    138
17  2020  fevereiro    144
18  2012      março     97
19  2013      março    101
20  2014      março    101
21  2015      março    123
22  2016      março    126
23  2017      março    138
24  2018      março    137
25  2019      março    154
26  2020      março    114
27  2012      abril     97
28  2013      abril     94
29  2014      abril     97
30  2015      abril    122
31  2016      abril    125
32  2017      abril    141
33  2018      abril    129
34  2019      abril    142
35  2020      abril      6
36  2012       maio     96
37  2013       maio     98
38  2014       maio     98
39  2015       maio    136
40  2016       maio    126
41  2017       maio    135
42  2018       maio    136
43  2019       maio    144
44  2020       maio      4
```

A minha intenção é ordenar por ano e por mes.

A forma que consegui foi mapeando os nomes dos meses para números de 1 a 12

```
meses_map = {
    'janeiro': 1,
    'fevereiro': 2,
    'março': 3,
    'abril': 4,
    'maio': 5,
    'junho': 6,
    'julho': 7,
    'agosto': 8,
    'setembro': 9,
    'outubro': 10,
    'novembro': 11,
    'dezembro': 12
}
```

Em seguida, apliquei o mapeamento para criar uma coluna 'mes_num':

```
df['mes_num'] = df['mes'].map(meses_map)
```

Só aí que consigo a ordem desejada: ordenando primeiro por 'ano' e depois por 'mes_num'

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ano', 'mes_num'])

print(df)

     ano        mes  valor  mes_num
0   2012    janeiro    112        1
9   2012  fevereiro    101        2
18  2012      março     97        3
27  2012      abril     97        4
36  2012       maio     96        5
1   2013    janeiro    127        1
10  2013  fevereiro    101        2
19  2013      março    101        3
28  2013      abril     94        4
37  2013       maio     98        5
2   2014    janeiro    121        1
11  2014  fevereiro     94        2
20  2014      março    101        3
29  2014      abril     97        4
38  2014       maio     98        5
3   2015    janeiro    131        1
12  2015  fevereiro    114        2
21  2015      março    123        3
30  2015      abril    122        4
39  2015       maio    136        5
4   2016    janeiro    150        1
13  2016  fevereiro    126        2
22  2016      março    126        3
31  2016      abril    125        4
40  2016       maio    126        5
5   2017    janeiro    158        1
14  2017  fevereiro    119        2
23  2017      março    138        3
32  2017      abril    141        4
41  2017       maio    135        5
6   2018    janeiro    137        1
15  2018  fevereiro    122        2
24  2018      março    137        3
33  2018      abril    129        4
42  2018       maio    136        5
7   2019    janeiro    165        1
16  2019  fevereiro    138        2
25  2019      março    154        3
34  2019      abril    142        4
43  2019       maio    144        5
8   2020    janeiro    164        1
17  2020  fevereiro    144        2
26  2020      março    114        3
35  2020      abril      6        4
44  2020       maio      4        5
```

Em suma, consegui a ordem desejada através de um "jeitinho" usando os números.

A minha questão é se seria possível fazer isso a partir dos próprior meses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode atingir o objetivo utilizando locale e o pandas:

```
import locale
import pandas as pd
```

Mudar o local para 'pt_BR' para português brasileiro

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
```

Data frame de teste

```
data = {
    'ano': [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]*5,
    'mes': ['janeiro']*9 + ['fevereiro']*9 + ['março']*9 + ['abril']*9 + ['maio']*9,
    'valor': [112, 127, 121, 131, 150, 158, 137, 165, 164,
              101, 101, 94, 114, 126, 119, 122, 138, 144,
              97, 101, 101, 123, 126, 138, 137,154 ,114,
              97 ,94 ,97 ,122 ,125 ,141 ,129 ,142 ,6,
              96 ,98 ,98 ,136 ,126 ,135 ,136 ,144 ,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

transformando em datetime e criando uma nova coluna, o astype str é para não dar erro na hora de concatenar as colunas de ano e mês. O 1 é para formar uma data completa para a conversão.

```
df["data"] = (pd
              .to_datetime("1 " + df["ano"].astype(str) + " " + df["mes"].astype(str),
                           format="%d %Y %B"))
```

ordenando o dataframe

```
df.sort_values("data").reset_index(drop=True)
```

|  | ano | mes | valor | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2012 | janeiro | 112 | 2012-01-01 |
| 1 | 2012 | fevereiro | 101 | 2012-02-01 |
| 2 | 2012 | março | 97 | 2012-03-01 |
| 3 | 2012 | abril | 97 | 2012-04-01 |
| 4 | 2012 | maio | 96 | 2012-05-01 |
| 5 | 2013 | janeiro | 127 | 2013-01-01 |
| 6 | 2013 | fevereiro | 101 | 2013-02-01 |
| 7 | 2013 | março | 101 | 2013-03-01 |
| 8 | 2013 | abril | 94 | 2013-04-01 |
| 9 | 2013 | maio | 98 | 2013-05-01 |
| 10 | 2014 | janeiro | 121 | 2014-01-01 |
| 11 | 2014 | fevereiro | 94 | 2014-02-01 |
| 12 | 2014 | março | 101 | 2014-03-01 |
| 13 | 2014 | abril | 97 | 2014-04-01 |

...

Caso queira pode excluir a coluna data após a ordenação.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode ordenar usando `datetime` lib e passando os meses como datas por exemplo `01/01/2023` para Janeiro, `01/02/2023` para fevereiro, e etc.
e depois passar o um `sort` do `datetime` nessa coluna, por exeplo

```
dates =  ["23 Jun 2018", "2 Dec 2017", "11 Jun 2018",  
          "01 Jan 2019", "10 Jul 2016", "01 Jan 2007"]   
  

dates.sort(key = lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%d %b %Y')) 


print(dates)
```

antes de printar na tela, você pode passar o `column.replace` na coluna de com as datas e substituir `01/01/2023` por `Janeiro`, assim

```
indice=0
for indice, row in df.iterrows():
    data= df['mes'].values[indice]
    data_str= str(data)
    data_final = data_str.replace('01/01/2023','Janeiro')
    indice+=1
```